# How to increment variable on click and update content from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm building a app to show the fixture off a football club. I have a json file with the data of the games and can show this based on the current week.

I want to make it possible to show the next game and a game before after click on the link.

I tried a lot but can't realize this.

To get the current week and show the match:

```
currentWeek = data[0].current_week;
day = data[0].weeks[currentWeek].day;

homeTeam = data[0].weeks[currentWeek].team1;
awayTeam = data[0].weeks[currentWeek].team2;
scoreHome = data[0].weeks[currentWeek].score1;
scoreAway = data[0].weeks[currentWeek].score2;
```

I tried this to update the current week, but doesn't work:

```
$( "#test" ).click(function() {
        currentWeek++;
    });
```

Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/gjm9yjoj/

How can I show the next game after clicking on

```
<li><a href="" id="test">WEEK LATER</a></li>
```

Comment: I was about to suggest that you attach `currentWeek` to window so it's available everywhere, BUT I believe you're already doing that. What you need to do is run a lot of the code that you have in your `$.getJSON('...', function() {})` callback function so that all the values are updated appropriately. You could either accomplish this by copy/pasting that function's code into an "updateWeek" method (that gets called when you run `currentWeek++`). Alternatively, you can refactor to reuse some of the code.

Comment: Something like this:

`$( "#test" ).click(function() {
        updateWeek = currentWeek++;

        day = data[0].weeks[updateWeek].day;

        homeTeam = data[0].weeks[updateWeek].team1;
        awayTeam = data[0].weeks[updateWeek].team2;
        scoreHome = data[0].weeks[updateWeek].score1;
        scoreAway = data[0].weeks[updateWeek].score2;

        homeCode = data[0].weeks[updateWeek].team1.code;
        awayCode = data[0].weeks[updateWeek].team2.code;
    });

`

this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your json-data and `currentWeek` in global scope and add function for results displaying: https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/gjm9yjoj/1/

Comment: this works only after clicking a few times on the link and after that it turns always back to the current week.

This happen http://d.pr/i/NdYr

Comment: Here is completely working example https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/gjm9yjoj/3/